# Ckeditor results in simple textarea with no wysiwyg buttons

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Hi I am trying to add ckeditor on another page of my asp.net website but something seems to be wrong because it appears as a textArea.Here is what I have done so far:

1.I registered the assembly:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

2.Added a path to ckeditor javascript file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/pluggins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

3.Added the Ckeditor controler:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

I have used ckeditor on another page like this and it worked.Is it something I am missing here because it results in only a textarea with none of the wysiwyg properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your `ckeditor.js` path is probably wrong or there is an unrelated js error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/pluggins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Is js your root path and do you have another js error preventing it from intializing?